# What is the "no fast-forwarding theorem"?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

As a newbie to Quantum,  I was reading some of the articles and ran into a no-fast-forwarding theorem, which is described "Simulating the dynamics of a quantum system for time T typically requires Ω(T) gates so that a generic Hamiltonian evolution cannot be achieved in sublinear time. This result is known as the **“no fast-forwarding theorem**”, and holds both for a typical unknown Hamiltonian and for the query model setting"

Does this mean that "there won't be any shorter-time algorithm than the required T?  I don't think I fully appreciate the implication or practical meaning of this.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There may be special classes of Hamiltonians that can be simulated by shorter time algorithms. For example, see this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09619). But, as this paper proves, if all generic physically realizable Hamiltonians can be fast-forwarded, then BQP=PSPACE, which is thought to be highly unlikely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In simple words, it means you can't simulate a quantum system faster than time evolves it. However, if you have an analytical solution to the system, you can get the answer faster in theory. As an example consider a simple pendulum that you want to simulate for $t= 5$ sec. If you do it physically with an actual pendulum you have to wait for $5$ sec to get the results. But we already know its analytical solution and can predict its evolution with certainty using mathematical equations. So we can simulate the same on a computer in less than a sec. However, for most natural processes this is not the case, specifically complicated Hamiltonians.